# How to stop findstr displaying any message in Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

I want to stop `findstr` displaying any messages and I am able to do that but I also want to extract `findstr` results as a text file and if I stop `findstr` to display messages like the following:

`FINDSTR: can't open anything.exe` Or `FINDSTR: Line 185369536 is too long`

By using `findstr /s /m "anything" "C:\*.*">nul 2>&1`

Then I can't display `findstr` results as a text file.

What is the code to extract `findstr` as a text file without displaying any `findstr` messages?

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr ..... >"myFile" 2>nul
```

redirects the stdout stream to a file and the stderr stream to nul. That way you save your valid data while hiding the errors